# Sonicwall 240, different subnets

Tags: subnet, sonicwall

I have sonicwall 240

for now

x0: Lan   192.168.25.1

x1: Wan   my internet connection

x2: DMZ   192.168.102.1

I want to add x3 as new subnet with this address 170.20.120.1
what should I do?

Thanks 
Regards

Answer (score 3):

Login into Management Interface using web browser. Navigate to Network > Interfaces. Click the Configure icon in the right column of the X3 interface. Choose zone and enter IP address details.
You do realize, that "170.20.120.1" is a public internet address and you shouldn't use it as a private subnet?